# Entity Framework Context Class

Tags: entity-framework

I was studying about Context Class and the functions it is responsible for;
What does it mean that Context class is reponsible for :to materialize the raw data returned from the database as entity objects??

Comment: Data comes from the sql server as rows with columns in each row holding the data.  The context is responsible for determining what object should hold the row and what properties of this object should be filled from which columns.  Taking the results of the query and creating objects using its data is called "materialization", in your quote.

Comment: Thanks for your answer